# Efficient way to look up dictionary

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, lookup

I have a dictionary, it map word to id, like:

```
at: 0
hello: 1
school: 2
fortune:3
high:4
we: 5
eat: 6
....
high_school: 17
fortune_cookie: 18
....
```

Then, i have a document. What is the fastest and efficient way to transfer content of document to id.
Eg:

```
"At high school, we eat fortune cookie."
=>  "0 17, 5 6 18"
```

Hope to see your suggestion.
Thank for readinng.

Comment: if say dictionary is my:1 name:2 my_name:3 and text is my name, what do you expect 3 or 1 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how large your document is, whether your keyword list is static, and whether you need to find multi-word phrases. The naive way to do it is to look up every word from the document in the dictionary. Because dictionary lookups are O(1), looking up every word will take O(n) time, where n is the number of words in the document. If you need to find multi-word phrases, you can post-process the output to find those.

That's not the most efficient way to do things, but it's really easy to implement, reasonably fast, and will work very well if your documents aren't *huge*.

If you have very large documents, then you probably want something like the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). That algorithm works in two stages. First it builds a trie from the words in your dictionary, and then it makes a single pass through the document and outputs all of the matches. It's more complicated to implement than the naive method, but it works very well once the trie is built. And, truth to tell, it's not *that* hard to implement. The original paper, which is linked from the Wikipedia article, explains the algorithm well and it's not difficult to convert their pseudocode into a working program.

Note, however, that you might get some unexpected results. For example, if your dictionary contains the words "high" and "school" as well as the two-word phrase "high school", the Aho-Corasick will give you matches for all three when it sees the phrase "high school".

Comment: First, thank for your response. I will try implement it, and your note that mean in my example, output is "0 4 2 17 ..."?

Comment: @yukO_Oshima: Yes, that would be your output.

Comment: @JimMischel:AFIK Aho-Corasik isn't just a dictionary but also finds Words not in the dictionary? You can achieve the same with a simple trie. For example you look for prefixes, too!? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Phpdna: No, it's not just a dictionary. It's an optimized trie and a state machine that can find multiple words or phrases in a single pass of a document. Although it was originally described to work by scanning the document one character at a time, it's easily modified to work on a word-by-word basis, so that you can avoid false positives like finding the word "highlight" when you're searching for the word "high".

Comment: @JimMischel:How is it helpful, I.e. what is the advantage?

Comment: @Phpdna: The Aho-Corasick algorithm will generally be faster than individual word lookup. It formalizes the use of a trie to drive a state machine, rather than depending on an *ad-hoc* implementation. And the algorithm is easily generalized to work with other data types. It's worth studying, if nothing else than to get a better appreciation of how powerful tries can be when used well.

Comment: @JimMischel:I see. It output matches in the dictionary. With my answer I was meaning something else. First off you need the dictionary. Second I didn't look at the states or failures. But it seems conplicated thing to implement and does it find multi -phrases?

Comment: @Phpdna: Yes, it can find multi-word phrases. It's not terribly complicated to implement. Rather than ask me a bunch of questions about it, read the Wikipedia article and read the original paper (linked from the article). It's a well-studied algorithm and used in a large number of applications.

Comment: @JimMischel:I see. I think you mean the dictionary must have the combine words.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a trie data structure or a red-black tree if the document hasn't so much duplicates. A trie is much less expensive. You can also combine a trie with a wildcard: http://phpir.com/tries-and-wildcards

Comment: what to do with composite words?

Comment: @AliAmiri: You can extend the trie to store n-order words. I.e. like tries in ppm compression.

Comment: yes you are right, I forget lots of things about red-black and binary search tree, your answer made me to read about them again thanks :)

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.